# MySql insert Trigger Not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a before insert trigger that will not insert the data in the tables if the 'ratings' > 5 and inserts it on a table 'rating_check' with a message .For 'ratings' <= 5 the data is inserted on all the tables.But its not working nor am I getting any errors. Here is the trigger code-

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
TRIGGER `mytrigger` BEFORE INSERT 
ON `review`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF NEW.ratings > 5 THEN
    SET @trigger_desc = 'You cannot rate greater than 5!';
    INSERT INTO `rating_check` (`trig_id`, `trigger_desc`) VALUES ('', @trigger_desc);

ELSE 
    INSERT INTO `developer_details` (`developer_id`,`developer_name`,`developer_email`) VALUES ('$appDevId','$appDevName','$appDevEmail');
    INSERT INTO `apps` (`app_id`,`app_name`,`app_icon`,`dev_id`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$appName','$appIcon','$appDevId');
    INSERT INTO `app_details` (`app_id`,`description`,`version`,`release_date`,`size`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$appDesc','$appVersion','$appDate','$appSize');
    INSERT INTO `app_specs` (`app_id`,`downloads`,`category_name`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$appDownloads','$appCategory');
    INSERT INTO `review` (`app_id`,`ratings`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$appRatings');

END IF;
END$$
```

'trig_id' is auto incremented here.Please help me with this!

Comment: You cannot insert into review because the trigger is on review. You should be getting an error on execution to this effect.

Comment: No,I,m not getting any kind of error while executing this.

Comment: Can u tell me some other way to do this.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to insert to review in the trigger, it would help me if you published your table definitions and insert statement in your question as text or sqlfiddle.

Comment: I actually have a large form asking about the details of an application which are inserted into the 5 tables in the else part.If the users input for the rating field is greater than 5 than i should not put any of the information on any of the tables and insert a message into the rating_check table with the trigger message.The review table is where the rating is inserted.So when all of the information are correct then the else part should execute. I'm actually new to triggers and don't know much about it.

Comment: It doesn't look as though you should be using a trigger at all. I am not expert in PHP so I'm going to drop out now.